Prove that for complete biclique Ki,j that ∆(Ki,j) = χ′(Ki,j).
I am trying to prove it by contradiction.
Proof:
"Assume that ∆(Ki,j) != χ′(Ki,j) for a complete biclique (Ki,j).
If ∆(Ki,j) > χ′(Ki,j), it implies that the minimum number of colors needed to color the edges is less than the maximum degree of the vertices. This means that there are not enough colors to color all i x j edges between partitions A and B, indicating missing edges.
If ∆(Ki,j) < χ′(Ki,j), it implies that there are not enough edges to utilize all the colors required for proper edge coloring. This would mean that there exist edges between two vertices of the same partition, which violates the definition of a bipartite graph."
But I am not sure if this is enough to prove the claim. Am I missing something to complete the proof.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This is not a proof. A proof must use the definitions of edge coloring (and, for that matter, of maximum degree) somehow.
